# Quiero agregar Código completo Escaneado a la Base de datos

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

Buenas tardes,
Estoy desarrollando una aplicación para Windows Mobile en Visual Studio 2008 con Visual Basic, sucede que escaneo un código de barra con el láser y lo muestro en un TextBox y ahí viene mi problema y necesito ayuda, el "número" del código de barra se va agregando de a poco en el TextBox y de la misma forma se va agregando en mi base de datos local.
**Ej: escaneo el código 8989898989 y se va agregando de la siguiente forma a mi base de datos: 
8
89
898
8989
89898
898989**
así sucesivamente hasta llegar a completar el código de barra, no se si tendré que hacer una pausa antes de ir agregando el código a la base de datos, favor ayuda. Adjunto el Código de mi TextBox:

```
Private Sub txtCodigo_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtCodigo.TextChanged
        Me.ProductoTableAdapter.AgregarCodigo(txtCodigo.Text) {{{el agregar codigo es un simple insert into a mi tabla}}}
        Me.ProductoTableAdapter.Fill(Me.PruebaProductosDataSet1.Producto) {{{esto me ayuda a refrescar la pantalla}}}
 End Sub
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

**Saludos**

Usa el evento KeyPress y evalua cuando se pulse ENTER; si mal no recuerdo los escaneos de código de barra al final "dan un enter".

Claro esta evalua si esta vacia; tienen **n** longitud permitida, etc; todas las consideraciones que apliquen pra tu sistema *(esto por si un usuario simplemente ingresa **uncodigodecaracteres** y pulsa tecla ENTER)*

Comment: Roberto ya solucione el problema, tu comentario me ayudo a encontrar la solución.

Answer (score 1):

Adjunto el código de la solución:

```
Private Sub txtCodigo_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtCodigo.KeyPress
        Try
            If Asc(e.KeyChar) = 13 Then
                Me.ProductoTableAdapter.AgregarCodigo(txtCodigo.Text)
                txtCodigo.Text = String.Empty
                Me.ProductoTableAdapter.Fill(Me.PruebaProductosDataSet1.Producto)
                txtCodigo.Focus()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Favor contactar al admin", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: ¿Que realiza este código? sería importante agregar una explicación que ayude a solucionar el mismo problema a otros usuarios.

Comment: Gracias jorge por tu comentario, ya solucione el problema